# How to make a panel of a Form Full Screen

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a TV Tuner application in vb.net and my video will be played on a panel and i want that panel to become full screen on a click of a button is it possible as seen in media players???

Comment: No i just want only a panel in that example all controls are to be set to proper place when that is made fullscreen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private sz As Size
Private pnt As Point

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

    pnt = Panel1.Location
    sz = Panel1.Size

    Panel1.Parent = Me
    Panel1.BringToFront()
    Panel1.Location = Me.Location
    Panel1.Size = Me.Size
End Sub
```

and return to normal by MouseDown event on the the panel:

```
Private Sub Panel1_MouseDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseDown
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal

    Panel1.Parent = GroupBox1
    Panel1.Location = pnt
    Panel1.Size = sz
    GroupBox1.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

Comment: Its working bro thanx just i have to change this for the group box in which this panel was present

Comment: @GTARaja It maximizes the form **and** the panel(what you wanted).

Comment: ya true but my panel was inside a groupbox so i have to specify the location and size parameters for them also..one more thing is there any method to revert back to previous state means default not full screen....thanx bro..

Comment: @GTARaja see my new answer